# Vesta. Create user. API. Не добавляется пользователь

Tags: php, api, curl, vesta

Пишу скрипт для добавление нового пользователя в панель управления хостингом "VESTA". Пишу согласно мануалу по api: http://vestacp.com/docs/api/ 
Ошибок при выполнении кода не выдает, но пользователь в весту не добавляется.
Мой код:

```
$vst_hostname = 'dfsdfl.csfdsdsgds.com';

$postvars = array(
$vst_username = 'zdeslogin',
$vst_password = 'zdesparol',
$vst_returncode = 'yes',
$vst_command = 'v-add-user',
$username = 'demo',
$password = 'd3m0p4ssw0rd',
$email = 'demo@gmail.com',
$package = 'default',
$fist_name = 'Rust',
$last_name = 'Cohle'
);

$postdata = http_build_query($postvars);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . $vst_hostname . ':8083/api/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$answer = curl_exec($curl);
// Check result
if($answer == 0) {
    echo "User account has been successfuly created\n";
} else {
    echo "Query returned error code: " .$answer. "\n";
}
```

После отработки кода, возвращается строка: User account has been successfuly created.

Comment: я заводил пользователя с самой панели управления Vesta  но он не имел прав никаких.

Comment: Задача такова, что нужно дергать весту через api. Через панель не вариант в моей ситуации.

Comment: Вы пытались связаться с разработчиками Vesta

Comment: Нет. Их консультация стоит 60$/час.

Comment: Видно, что вы не читали док по api. Если 0, то все ок, если число от 1 до 20, то ошибка. А проверка эта взята из документации. Протокол точно https.

Comment: у вас массив $postvars не верный.Аж страшно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80374/discussion-between---and-spartak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// пример массива

```
$postvars = array(
    'user' => $vst_username,

);
```

А у вас вместо "Ключа массива" переменная, ключи массива оставьте как в оригинале API , и только значения установите.

У вас должна быть Веб форма с полями текстовыми для регистрации Юзера.
Переменную  $vst_username задайте через веб форму методом Post.

Затем передайте все значения в скрипт API.

Можно и без формы, в начале скрипта АPI просто назначьте переменные. А они у вас в массиве.Вытащите их в самое начало скрипта.

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. Спасибо.

Comment: @китаец ИзКитая
Спасибо огромное. Работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, собственно, рабочий код.

```
<?php

// Server credentials
$vst_hostname = 'sadsad.sadsad.com';

$vst_username = 'zdeslogin';
$vst_password = 'zdesparol';
$vst_returncode = 'no';
$vst_command = 'v-add-user';
$username = 'demo3';
$password = 'd3m0p4ssw0rd';
$email = 'demo@gmail.com';
$package = 'default';
$fist_name = 'Rust';
$last_name = 'Cohle';

$postvars = array(
    'user' => $vst_username,
    'password' => $vst_password,
    'returncode' => $vst_returncode,
    'cmd' => $vst_command,
    'arg1' => $username,
    'arg2' => $password,
    'arg3' => $email,
    'arg4' => $package,
    'arg5' => $fist_name,
    'arg6' => $last_name
);
$postdata = http_build_query($postvars);

// Send POST query via cURL
$postdata = http_build_query($postvars);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://' . $vst_hostname . ':8083/api/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$answer = curl_exec($curl);

// Check result
if($answer == 0) {
    echo "User account has been successfuly created\n";
} else {
    echo "Query returned error code: " .$answer. "\n";
}

?>
```